# Aligning the headers in gridview with an item and moving the item content to right

Tags: css, asp.net

I have a very simple gridview like so:

[image]

I want to align header with the content so shirts should come underneath header Item. Description needs to moved to the left and price 336 should be moved to the right. I want it something like this:

[image]

Below is my code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdShoppingCart" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" class="ui-responsive table-stroke ss-table ui-search-result-table" GridLines="None">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="item" HeaderText="Item" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" ItemStyle-Width="35%"  />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" ItemStyle-Width="35%"  >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblDesc" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("desc") %>' /><br />
                        &nbsp;Requested By: &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblDesc1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RequestedBy") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>

                </asp:TemplateField>
                   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity" ItemStyle-Width="10%" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                            <input type="number" id="txtQuantity" value='<%# Eval("Quantity") %>'   style="text-align:right;" data-mini="true" min="1" max="100" runat="server"/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price" ItemStyle-Width="100%" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label  ID="lblPrice" runat="server" Text= '<%# Int32.Parse(Eval("Quantity").ToString()) * 28 %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>



 </asp:GridView>
```

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try this;

```
<asp:Label id="Label1" runat="server" width="100px" style="text-align: right;" />
```